# it crash on 6488 ! exit code is code=3221225725

Tags: c

i try to code a program which has to find prime numbers from 5 to a maximum number , the biggest number it can find is 64927 , and it is a prime number ( i think it has the 6489th place in prime numbers) . when i set max_list_size to 6488 , programm work normally and exit with 0, but for grater number it crash and exit whit code=3221225725 ( a bug in the executed software that causes stack overflow, leading to abnormal termination of the software) , can you help me guys ?

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
long to_which_index ();
void is_prime();
void pluse_two();
void write_to_arrays();
long* prime_numbers;
long current_number = 5;
long next_prime_number = 0;
void terminate ();
long max_list_size = 6488;
int main()
{
prime_numbers = (long*)calloc(max_list_size,sizeof(long));
prime_numbers[0] = 3;

is_prime(current_number);

    
    
}
//is prime 
void is_prime()
{
    int to_which = to_which_index();
    for (long i = 0; i <= to_which; i++)
    {
        //(current_number % prime_numbers[i] == 0) ? pluse_two() : continue ;
        if((current_number % prime_numbers[i]) == 0)
        {
            pluse_two();
        }
    }
    write_to_arrays();
    
}

// pluse_2
void pluse_two()
{
    current_number = current_number +2;
    is_prime();
}

//write
void write_to_arrays()
{
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("G:/Code/files_to_accses/prime_numbers.txt","a");
    next_prime_number ++;
    prime_numbers[next_prime_number] = current_number;
    fprintf(fptr,"%i\n",current_number);
    fclose(fptr);
    terminate();
}

//terminate programm
void terminate ()
{
    if (next_prime_number ==(max_list_size - 1))
    {
        free(prime_numbers);
        exit(0);
    }
    pluse_two();

}

//from index 0 to which index whe should check?
long to_which_index ()
{
    for (long i = 0; i < (next_prime_number+1); i++)
    {
        //( prime_numbers[i] < ceil(sqrt(double(current_number))) ) ? continue: return i;
        if( prime_numbers[i] < ceil(sqrt(current_number)) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{
            return i;
        }
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55 - 3221225725 (0xc000000d) is listed there as STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run out of stack becuase you recurse too deep, finding primes is not reall a good use of recursion

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAAC6E341C (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000003902E03FF8).

[image]

For me it died when current_number == 2801

Also this function

```
long to_which_index()
{
    for (long i = 0; i < (next_prime_number + 1); i++)
    {
        //( prime_numbers[i] < ceil(sqrt(double(current_number))) ) ? continue: return i;
        if (prime_numbers[i] < ceil(sqrt(current_number)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return i;
        }
    }
```

}

doesnt return a value all the time (thats not the casue tho)

---

Here is your recursion

```
//is prime 
void is_prime()   <<<<===================================|
{                                                        | 
    int to_which = to_which_index();                     |
    for (long i = 0; i <= to_which; i++)                 |
    {                                                    |
        //(current_number % prime_numbers[i] == 0) ? pluse_two() : continue ;                                                   |
        if ((current_number % prime_numbers[i]) == 0)    |
        {                                                |
            pluse_two();========================|        |
        }                                       |        |
    }                                           |        |
    write_to_arrays();                          |        |
                                                |        |
}                                               |        |
                                                |        |
// pluse_2                                      |        | 
void pluse_two() <<<<<<======================== |        |    
{                                                        |
    current_number = current_number + 2;                 |
    is_prime(); ==========================================
}
```

you can see it plainly in the stack trace I added as a screen shot

Just change that plus_two function like this

```
void pluse_two()
{
    current_number = current_number + 2;
  //  is_prime();
}
```

Comment: if you mean a recursive function, I do not understand where to use the recursive function I have done, the main part of the problem is the iteration over the prime numbers that the program has already found! I think the for loop is not considered a recursive function, because it does not call itself!
If you think of other functions, I do not understand the concept of deepening, in addition to each prime number, each function calls another function once at level one and returns to the a loop.

Comment: And in the case of the to_which_index function, I think it returns a value every time it sounds,
Because he goes between the list of numbers and finds a number that is greater than the second tide of the current number, and he certainly finds it. If you do not agree with me, can you give me a number?

Comment: @DanialHamedi I suspect you just want to return there

Comment: @DanialHamedi now fixed , see last edit

Comment: Thank you very much, I noticed the problem, thank you for guiding me!
Do you know how I can solve the problem? I think if I combine the pluse_two function and the is_prime function, the program can find more prime numbers before it explodes (=
If I do this with one of the functional programming languages(like python), will I still have trouble?

Comment: @DanialHamedi did you see that commenting out that recursion call works fine (see last edit). Python would fail the same way